# Coefficients of 0,1-polynomials factorization

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, factorization

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $P_{n}$ is $0,1$-polynomial whose coefficients *are binary digits* of $n$.
Let $Q_{1}(x) \cdot Q_{2}(x) \cdots Q_{m}(x)$ - polynomial factorization (over integers) of $P_{n}$.
As was [shown here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462232/simple-question-about-0-1-polynomials), all $Q_{k}$ will also be $0,1$-polynomials iff there are no carries when multiplying prime factors of $n$.

Well, what happens in other cases?
According to numerical observations, in approximately half of the cases all $Q_{k}$ are ${-1, 0, 1}$-polynomials.
But for $n=141$ we have
$$P_{141}=(x+1) \left(x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+2 x^2-x+1\right)$$
— coefficient $2\notin\{-1, 0, 1\}$ firstly appears.
For $n=663$
$$P_{663}=(1 + x) (1 + x^2 - x^3 + 2 x^4 - 2 x^5 + 2 x^6 - x^7 + x^8)$$
$-2$ appears first times,
for $n=2229\rightarrow3$, $25767\rightarrow 4$ etc.

Is there a pattern to new coefficients appearances?
Will all integers appear sooner or later?
I tried to apply the considerations from the previous answer, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be odd. We have the factorization $x^n+1 =
-\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(-x)$, where $\Phi_d(x)$ is a cyclotomic
polynomial. Every integer is the coefficient of some cyclotomic
polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$. See reference [120] of C. Sanna, [arXiv:2111.04034](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.04034.pdf).
It's easy to see that we can assume that $n$ is odd.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: corrected.